# Disable button if one of the checkboxes are not checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I have two checkboxes in `HTML` called `accepttermsandcond-checkbox` and `accepttermsandcond-checkbox` and I made a Button called `startusing-button`

I want the `startusing-button` to stay disabled, if one of these checkboxes are not checked.

The problem is that it disables it right now in the beginning, but if I check both, it doesn't enable the button.

***Note:** even if I add `document.getElementById('startusing-button').disabled = false;` to the code it doesn't solve the issue*

**How could I make the button to be enabled only if both of the checkboxes are checked?**

**Edit: I forgot to mention that I have a lot of checkboxes and buttons. It would be ideal if the solution only affected these two checkboxes with one button, leaving the rest of the checkboxes and buttons alone.**

```js
    var ebpDocumentCheckboxid = document.getElementById('document-checkboxid');
    var ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox =document.getElementById('accepttermsandcond-checkbox');

            if (ebpDocumentCheckboxid.checked && ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox.checked) { 
              
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('startusing-button').disabled = true;

            }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox"/>


<button type="button" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
```

Comment: rather than trying to find and modify the dom elements - you should bind the disabled attribute to the data nd update the data when the button should be disabled and when it should be enabled.

Comment: _"but if I check both, it doesn't enable the button"_ - that's good then, isn't it? Because you explicitly said you did _not_ want that. (_"Note: I don't want to enable it if both are checked"_)

Comment: I am open for any advices, I choose modifying the DOM because this seemed the easiest solution.

Comment: CBroe, I am gonna edit the text, and make it more clear.

Comment: you have said _I don't want to enable it if both are checked_  and _How could I make the button to be enabled only if both of the checkboxes are checked_ Which is it?

Comment: When the check boxes are changed check if both are checked and set the button disabled based on that.

Comment: Craicerjack - You are right, I didn't explain it well, I deleted the Note because it did not help and made my question less understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger `change` of checkboxes.

Simply checking both checkboxes have checked or not, will work only on the loading of document. You have to repeat this process each time the checkbox status is changed.

I have modified your script a little bit.

Logic

- Select all checkboxes using `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')`.
- Add a change event on checkbox by looping this list using `forEach`.
- Inside the change event, find the count of selected checkboxes.
- If that matches to the length of total check box, enable the button, or disable it.

```js
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('startusing-button');
checkBoxes.forEach((cb) => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', checkButtonStatus);
});
function checkButtonStatus() {
  const checkedCount = [...checkBoxes].filter((cb) => cb.checked);
  submitButton.disabled = checkedCount.length !== checkBoxes.length
}
checkButtonStatus();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid" />
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox" />

<button type="button" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to select only the two checkboxes, you can handle this in multiple ways. You can use some custom attribute with some unique value. Here in the below example I use `identifier="my-custom-identifier"` and make the inputs selection with `document.querySelectorAll('input[identifier="my-custom-identifier"]')`. This will check for all input elements with the `identifier` having value `my-custom-identifier`.

Why I use this approach is to make your solution a little more generic. You just have to use `identifier="my-custom-identifier"` in all inputs where you want to include for this checking.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[identifier="my-custom-identifier"]');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('startusing-button');
checkBoxes.forEach((cb) => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', checkButtonStatus);
});
function checkButtonStatus() {
  const checkedCount = [...checkBoxes].filter((cb) => cb.checked);
  submitButton.disabled = checkedCount.length !== checkBoxes.length
}
checkButtonStatus();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid" identifier="my-custom-identifier" />
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox" identifier="my-custom-identifier" />
<button type="button" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
```

If you still want to make use of only 2 element by picking them with id, you could select them using ids. Like `document.querySelector('input[id="document-checkboxid"]')` and `document.querySelector('input[id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox"]')` and bind change event to them. Inside the change event, check whether both are checked inside the change function.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const checkBox1 = document.querySelector('input[id="document-checkboxid"]');
const checkBox2 = document.querySelector('input[id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox"]');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('startusing-button');

checkBox1.addEventListener('change', checkButtonStatus);
checkBox2.addEventListener('change', checkButtonStatus);

function checkButtonStatus() {
  const allChecked = checkBox1.checked && checkBox2.checked;
  submitButton.disabled = !allChecked;
}
checkButtonStatus();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid" />
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox" />
<button type="button" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

May I ask how I could change it if there are multiple checkboxes but I only want this functionality for these two buttons?

Comment: @Norbs please check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT#2:** I updated the answer to have coverage both for *required* and *optional* checkboxes, as requested in comments.

**EDIT:** just noticed it still can be accessed with keyboard tab focus and fire the event. So not a perfect solution, note this.

This can be done with plain CSS:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
}

input[required]:not(:checked) ~ button {
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
  color: #d0d0d0;
  border: 1px outset #808080;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>ID:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid" required />
  <label>T&amp;C</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox" required />
  <hr />
  <label>Something irrelevant:</label><input type="checkbox" name="optional_one" id="something" />
  <label>Also optional:</label><input type="checkbox" name="optional_two" id="something else" />
  <hr />
  <button type="submit" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I still like this answer a lot because I did not know something like this is possible with pure css :D

Comment: I really love this solution.
If I understand it well, It influences every input types in the file.
I am working in a larger project, with many input fields and buttons. Is it possible to change it to influence only these two checkmarks and that one button?

Comment: @Norbs I updated the answer to cover your needs also for required/optional checkup

Comment: One more question: 
What if I have more buttons, but I want this ` CSS`  funcionality only on this one button?

For example, I have three buttons, but I only want to disable my `startusing-button`

Comment: @Norbs - use classes / ids for that. You can target css selectors precisely with them

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct you want the button to be only enabled when both checkboxes are checked, right? If so you could try something like this:

```
var ebpDocumentCheckboxid = document.getElementById("document-checkboxid");
var ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox = document.getElementById(
  "accepttermsandcond-checkbox"
);
var btn = document.getElementById("startusing-button");

const onCheckboxChanged = ()=>{
  btn.disabled = (!ebpDocumentCheckboxid.checked) || (!ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox.checked);
}

ebpDocumentCheckboxid.onchange = onCheckboxChanged;
ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox.onchange = onCheckboxChanged;
```

I also added `disabled="true"` to the button so its disabled from the start.

Here is a codepen of a working example: https://codepen.io/jonas_weinhardt/pen/QWgoGzL?editors=1010

**Edit:**

You should probably use Nitheesh answer because its a much simpler and general approach!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, more simple and readable(I hope).

```js
(()=>{
    let checkboxes = [
        document.querySelector('#document-checkboxid'),
        document.querySelector('#accepttermsandcond-checkbox')
    ];
    let button = document.querySelector('#startusing-button');

    for(let checkbox of checkboxes) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', changeStatus); // changeStatus function onclick
    }

    changeStatus(); // run changeStatus function automatically

    function changeStatus(){
        if(checkboxes.every(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        else button.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    }
})();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox"/>


<button type="button" id="startusing-button">CreateSubscription</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

i add value "disabled" to button and create two onclick method to get .checked status, and if both are true change button parameter "disabled=true" to "disabled=false"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  
<div id = "test">
<input type="checkbox" id="document-checkboxid" onclick="firstchb()"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="VAT" id="accepttermsandcond-checkbox" onclick="secondchb()"/>


<button type="button" id="button" disabled >CreateSubscription</button>
  
</div>

</body>
<script>

let ebpDocumentCheckboxid = null;
let ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox = null;
function firstchb(){
ebpDocumentCheckboxid = document.getElementById('document-checkboxid').checked;
enableit();
}

function secondchb(){
ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox = document.getElementById('accepttermsandcond-checkbox').checked;

enableit();
}
function enableit(){
  if (ebpDocumentCheckboxid == true && ebpAcceptTermsandCondCheckbox == true) { 
              document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
              
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;

            }
}
            
</script>
</html>
```